# Conditional Rendering of Components with Same Props in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component

I have a simple conditional test that I am running to see which component to render.  If the condition is true, I render one component, false the other component.  Right now this is how my code looks something like this:

```
    {isPresent && (
        <FirstComponent
          propOne="value one"
          propTwo="value two"
          {...props}
        />
    )}
    {!isPresent && (
        <SecondComponent
          propOne="value one"
          propTwo="value two"
          {...props}
        />
    )}
```

What I want to know is whether or not I can make this code a bit DRYer.  Something like this:

```
{isPresent && (
    <FirstComponent
        {propList}
    />
)}
{!isPresent && (
    <SecondComponent
        {propList}
    />
)}
```

Where `propList` represents all of the props that I want to include in each of these components.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: how do you decide proplist value ? is already handled or you need to handle based on isPresent ?

Comment: The props values have nothing to do with `isPresent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both elements have the same properties, then you can store these properties into a constant and pass it to the target Component

```
function YourComponent(props) {
  const commonProps = {
      propOne: "value one",
      propTwo: "value two",
      ...props
   };

   const Component = isPresent ? FirstComponent : SecondComponent;
   return <Component {...commonProps}/>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that did it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variable in render to define which component you want to render

```
 let Comp = isPresent ? FirstComponent : SecondComponent
 let propList = {
    propOne :"value one",
    propTwo : "value two",
    ...props
 }
```

Then in your return you can use

```
 <Comp
   { propList }
 />
```

***Note:-*** Always name the variable with first letter capital if you're assigning it a component, because `In JSX, lower-case tag names are considered to be HTML tags`

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated.